# Language question: record field with an anonymous record(?) as type...?

Tags: delphi, record, anonymous-types

I'm still learning Delphi/OP and stumbled upon the below (simplified) code that's part of an exercise in an old Delphi book.

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    FField1: Integer;
    FField2: String;

    FAnonRec: record
      FAnonField: Integer;
    end;

    FField3: Boolean;
  end;
```

My main question is:
1. What would `FAnonRec` - or rather, it's type - be called, in language terms? How do I *refer* to it? Something like *record field of anonymous record type*...? Just *constructed type*...? - I googled my question for some time but kept getting results about ancient Greek history... The closest I found was [this error explanation](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/topics/en/E2433_Method_declarations_not_allowed_in_anonymous_record_or_local_record_type_(Object_Pascal)).

Further questions:
2. In general, what is this type of construction called ("creating the type" right then and there instead of using a pre-declared named type)? - regardless of whether it's used as in the example or in a `var` block or even if no record is used.
3. The "Structure" tool in Delphi only shows `FField1` and `FField2`:
[image: delphi structure]
- yet the "Class Explorer" tool shows the entire record:
[image]
- anybody know why?
4. Point 3 and the fact that this is from an old book and the fact that I have a hard time finding any more info about it make me wonder whether that kind of construction is maybe outdated/discouraged?

Comment: The documentation covers this construction but does not name it. Anonymous record type, or nameless record type would describe it. But there seems to be no official delphi name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call it a "nested record type definition". It exists since the beginning of Turbo Pascal IIRC, and has nothing to do with "anonymous methods", introduced recently (at least in this century), which is a much more complex beast, since it grabs some execution context with it.

I don't see any reason why it may be seen as outdated or discouraged. It is a perfect valid structure, which makes sense, from the code point of view, since it gather some fields in a logical parent field. Of course, if you expect to access it independently, a dedicated type definition is worth it. Performance will be the same, it would be just more convenient if YAGNI (less typing, whole record seen at a glance).

So you can start by writing such nested records, then define a dedicated type when needed - e.g. if adding some methods could make your code more readable and maintainable. In practice, using nested records in type definitions could reduce eventual code change in your code base, since adding an explicit type definition later on won't break the way to access its members from existing code.

Note that there is RTTI for it, as a stand-alone record, named after the "main" record (something like `'__TMyRec_FAnonRec'`). So from the RTTI point of view, it is not anonymous. ;)

Comment: Nested isn't a good choice. You can define a local or global variable using an inline record declaration. Likewise a field in a class. Inline, anonymous, nameless are all better choices.

Comment: I would also call them nested records. They **are** nested and they are not nameless (the FAnonRec above clearly has a name). The **type** does not have a name, but neither does the static array type in, e.g. `var A: array[1..2] of Integer;`.

Comment: @Rudy The variable obviously has a name. The question is about the type though.  The type does not have a name. There is nothing special about nesting in terms of the type. The rules for variables of such types are the same if they are nested inside a compound type, declared as global variables, declared as local variables etc. What is special about this type is that it is declared *inline* and is *anonymous*. I mean, you presumably would not refer to a local variable `var foo: record bar: integer; end;` as being nested in any way. Or is that what you are saying?

Comment: @David: I would call `FAnonRec` a nested record (answering #2). The type would be anonymous, indeed, but for that it doesn't matter whether it is nested or not. I don't particularly like *declared inline* (although it can be considered correct), as that might cause confusion with the new inline declared *variables*.

Comment: @Rudy No. Question 2 is about the type and not the variable also.